# Resize image by excluding zero and NaNs

Tags: python, opencv

I want to resize my image, but my image has lots of zeros and NaN. I want to resize by excluding zeros and NaN.

The code so far I have is:

```
# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Generate sample data with zero and NaNs
a = np.zeros(shape=(8,8))
a[0] = [1,1,3,3,5,5,7,0]
a[1] = [1,0,3,0,5,0,0,7]
a[2] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a[3] = [1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8]
a[4] = [1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8]
a[5] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a[6] = [2,2,3,4,5,0,7,8]
a[7] = [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a[1:3,5] = np.nan

# Replace nan with zero (or zero with nan)
# a[np.isnan(a)] = 0
a[a==0] = np.nan

# Resize (8x8) array into (4x4)
c = cv2.resize(a,(4,4),cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

The problem is that it includes zeros and NaN when averaging. I also replaced zeros with NaNs or vice versa. I also tried with `INTER_NEAREST, INTER_LINEAR`, etc but the result remains the same.

Comment: You have to extrapolate what you think `a` should look like at `0` or `nan` first, which is more to do with image processing. If they're invalid pixels, what are you going to do? Take the average of the closest values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the sequence:

1. generate inpaint mask with your nan's and zeros.
2. apply [cv2.Inpaint](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) to fill the masked pixels with interpolated values
3. do resize